# Either of JQuery .css() or .hover() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

[My Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/1nQKHwT0c7aerI95h5Lb?p=preview) (Launch in full window).

My JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#play_buttton").hover(
        function () {
            $('#play_button').css({ "height": "240px", "width": "250px" });
        },
        function () {
            $('#play_button').css({ "height": "225px", "width": "220px" });
        }
    );
});
```

I think that this code must be creating the problem.

**Problem**: When , I hover over the image (#play_button) , nothing happens and its height and width don't change.Can anyone tell me how do I fix that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be `play_button` not `play_buttton`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#play_button").hover(   // Here not play_buttton
        function () {
            $(this).css({ "height": "240px", "width": "250px" });
        },
        function () {
            $(this).css({ "height": "225px", "width": "220px" });
        }
    );
});
```

See this sample [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eTBQF/).

You can also `.animate` it like in this [**FIDDLE2**](http://jsfiddle.net/eTBQF/1/)

Comment: Working suddenly, Thanks ,but where's the difference !

Comment: "You can also .animate"  Nice new method !

Answer (score 1):

Wrong spell at $("#play_butt**t**on").hover